# Searching in unsorted string array

Tags: java, binary-search

I have this array of strings

```
private static String[] colorsArray = { "#bde876", "#ff8581", "#ffc472",
    "#faed75", "#a8c9e5", "#999999", "#e3a8e5", "#dddddd", "#fc603c",
    "#ffcc00", "#74e8d4", "#3cd6fc" };
```

Then I have this method

```
public static int getColorByString(String color) {
    return Arrays.binarySearch(colorsArray, color);
}
```

When I call `getColorByString("#ff8581");` it gives me `-13` as result.

If I understood well, it means that the element is not contained in my array.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it work?

**EDIT**

I just realized the array has to be sorted. The problem is I can't sort it, because I need to map the strings to a specific index.

So now the question becomes, is there any method that performs a linear search or do I have to write it?

Comment: Just a note, I realise that your array is declared as static. That may have some undesired effect on what you want to do unless you are sure that it is used in a thread-safe way.

Comment: @tim_wonil Does it helps it never gets modified?

Comment: yes, if it never gets modified, I believe it is safe enough for our purpose here. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
Arrays.<String>asList(colorArray).indexOf("#ff8581");
```

Comment: While you are at it, you might consider making your `String[]` into a `List<String>`.  This gives you access to more methods easily, and prevents the overhead of creating new `List` objects every time you want to use one of those methods.